# Getting Unity Array (int[]) from Parse

Tags: arrays, get, unity-game-engine, parse-platform, int

I'm new in Parse and I've a problem I can't solve. 
I've uploaded a Parse **'int'** Array from **Unity** with this code to User's Group:

```
public int[] LVLOk;

{
var user = new ParseUser()
{
    Username = FB.UserId,
    Password = *******,
};
user["LevelOk"] = LVLOk;
user.SignUpAsync();
Debug.Log("Created");
}
```

However, when I want to get this Array, saved in Parse, onto a new variable in my **Unity code**, I've a problem, it doesn't get that values:

```
    public int[] ToLVLOk; 
ToLVLOk = ParseUser.CurrentUser.Get<int[]>("LevelOk");
```

I know this code works because it imports values when they're numbers or text, but I can't do anyhing when It's a list... 
Please, somebody who could help me with this problem. I'll be very glad! 
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

IList<int> ToLVLOk = ParseUser.CurrentUser.Get<IList<int>>("LevelOk");
```

Comment: No, It doesn't work. Unity does't let me doing this. It appears this error: "errorCS0308: The non-generic type `System.Collection.IList` cannot be used with the type arguments". I've been trying to change the type of the variable to another IList, but I show again this error... Another idea?

Comment: using System.Collections.Generic;

Comment: Great!! We've done a step, there isn't any error, but, now, I've another problem: The list hasn't imported to the array, there aren't values there. I've debugged it an it appears: "`Parse.Internal.FlexibleListWrapper ' 2[System.Int32, System.Object]`". In my original array, all values are 0 and, in Parse, they all are correct. Please, can you help me again?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about the Unity version of the Parse framework, but in the iOS version, when you retrieve an array as part of a Parse Object, you need to then go fetch each individual member of the array.  The first get is just a placeholder.  Could that be the issue?  If your array is just an array of ints, then that's probably not the issue.

When you create the int array in the first place, do you save it (to Parse)?